# How can I use php to query mysql and convert "5/9/2018 10:15:19" to "2018-05-09 10:15:19"

Tags: php, mysql

Could anyone help convert "5/9/2018 10:15:19" to "2018-05-09 10:15:19" using php "explode"method?

First question ever here ... be gentle on me!

Comment: Step 1: Read up on what [date functions PHP has](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). `explode` is not the right tool here.

Comment: https://wpartisan.me/tutorials/php-validate-check-dates may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, there is a better way to achieve this but if you must use explode then this code will do the job.

```
<?php

$input = '5/9/2018 10:15:19';

$date_and_time = explode(' ', $input);
$date = $date_and_time[0];
$time = $date_and_time[1];

$split_date = explode('/', $date);
$year = $split_date[2];
$month = $split_date[1];
$day = $split_date[0];

$output = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' ' . $time;

echo $output;
```